# Amcharts5: legend errors in multiline chart

Tags: javascript, visualization, amcharts, amcharts5

I am using amchart5 to render some multi line data and I have some issues with how the data is being rendered.

1. I cannot add currency symbols to the labels of the y-axis
2. I cant turn the labels of the x-axis so they are more vertical rather than horizontal
3. The preview will not show any lines

How can I resolve this?

See image:
[image]

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    am5.ready(function() {

    // Create root element
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
    var root = am5.Root.new("fundChartLine");
    
    root.numberFormatter.setAll({
        numberFormat: "#,###.##00",
    });

    // Set themes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
    root.setThemes([
        am5themes_Animated.new(root),
        am5themes_Responsive.new(root),
        Amdg.new(root)
    ]);
    // Create chart
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
    var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
        panX: true,
        panY: true,
        wheelX: "panX",
        wheelY: "zoomX",
        pinchZoomX:true
        }));
    // Add cursor
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
    var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
    behavior: "none"
    }));
    cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);



    // Define data
    var data = {{ line_chart_data| safe }}
    // Create axes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
    // Create Y-axis
    let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
    am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
    })
    );

    // Create X-Axis
    /*var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
    am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        maxDeviation: 0.2,
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
        categoryField: "chart_dates"
    })
    );
    xAxis.data.setAll(data);*/

    var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
        am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
            groupData: true,
            baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
            renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
            minGridDistance: 30
            })
        })
        );

    xAxis.get("dateFormats")["day"] = "MM/dd";
    xAxis.get("periodChangeDateFormats")["day"] = "MMMM";
    
    xAxis.data.setAll(data);
    // Add series
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/line-series/
    function createSeries(name, field) {
    var series = chart.series.push( 
        am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, { 
        name: name,
        xAxis: xAxis, 
        yAxis: yAxis, 
        valueYField: field, 
        categoryXField: "chart_dated_dt",
        stacked: false
        //legendLabelText: "[{fill}]{category}[/]",
        //legendValueYText: "[bold {fill}]ZAR{valueY}[/]"

        })
    );
    
    series.strokes.template.setAll({
        strokeWidth: 2,
        //strokeDasharray: [2,1]
    });
    series.fills.template.setAll({
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        visible: false
    });
    series.data.setAll(data);
    
    //series.labels.template.set("visible", false);
    //series.ticks.template.set("visible", false);
    
    console.log(series)        
}

    
    chart.topAxesContainer.children.push(am5.Label.new(root, {
        text: "Performance",
        fontSize: 30,
        fontColor: '#e40505',
        fontWeight: "500",
        textAlign: "center",
        x: am5.percent(50),
        centerX: am5.percent(50),
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingBottom: 20,
    }));



    createSeries("Average Contributions", "average_contrib");
    createSeries("Average Contributions + Interest", "average_totals");
    createSeries("Median Contributions", "median_contrib");
    createSeries("Median Contributions + Interest", "median_totals");
    createSeries("Your Contributions", "user_contrib");
    createSeries("Your Contributions + Interest", "user_totals");

    
    //var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {}));
    //legend.data.setAll(chart.series.values);
    var legend = chart.bottomAxesContainer.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
        centerX: am5.percent(50),
        x: am5.percent(50),
        useDefaultMarker: true,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 20,
        layout: am5.GridLayout.new(root, {
            maxColumns: 3,
            fixedWidthGrid: true
        })
    }));
    legend.data.setAll(chart.series.values);

    // Add scrollbar
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/scrollbars/

    /*var scrollbarX = am5.Scrollbar.new(root, {
        orientation: "horizontal"
        });*/

    var scrollbarX = am5xy.XYChartScrollbar.new(root, {
        orientation: "horizontal",
        height: 50
        });
    
    //chart.bottomAxesContainer.children.push(scrollbarX);
    /*let sbxAxis = scrollbarX.chart.xAxes.push(
        am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        maxDeviation: 0.2,
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
            opposite: false,
            strokeOpacity: 0
        }),
        categoryField: "chart_dates"
        })
    );*/
    
    let sbxAxis = scrollbarX.chart.xAxes.push(
        am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
            groupData: true,
            groupIntervals: [{ timeUnit: "year", count: 1 }],
            baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
            renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
                opposite: false,
                strokeOpacity: 0
            })
        })
        );

    let sbyAxis = scrollbarX.chart.yAxes.push(
        am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
            renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
        })
    );

    let sbseries = scrollbarX.chart.series.push(
        am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
            xAxis: sbxAxis,
            yAxis: sbyAxis,
            valueYField: "user_totals", 
            valueXField: "chart_dated_dt",
        })
        );
    sbseries.strokes.template.setAll({
        strokeWidth: 2,
        //strokeDasharray: [2,1]
    });
    sbseries.data.setAll(data);
    chart.set("scrollbarX", scrollbarX);
    console.log(sbseries.data.values[0]["user_totals"])
    console.log(sbseries.data.values[0]["chart_dated_dt"])




    // Make stuff animate on load
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
    root._logo.dispose();
    chart.appear(1000, 100);
    }); // end am5.ready()
```

I've looked at the docs and at some questions here and still stuck-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the currency I added the currency symbol  within the number formatter:

   root.numberFormatter.setAll({
   numberFormat: "'ZAR '#,###.##00",
   tooltipNumberFormat: "'ZAR '#,###.##00",
2. I didn't figure out how to handle the formatting of the legend but what I did instead was change the date data from a Category value with a string to a an actual which allowed me to change the axis into a date one. Amcharts naturally handles the formatting of this in such a way that my problem disappeared and it also fit my long terms data goals for the chart. The category was a story gap.
3. The preview had isues with my date compile. I noticed in the code when converting the date I was simply making the date object but not actually getting the time. By using the the get_time i was able to properly render the x-axis. This issue aslo affected number 2.

   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   data[i]["chart_dated_dt"] = new Date(data[i]["chart_dated_dt"]).getTime();
   }

Full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    am5.ready(function() {

        // Create root element
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
        var root = am5.Root.new("fundChartLine");
        
        root.numberFormatter.setAll({
            numberFormat: "'ZAR '#,###.##00",
            tooltipNumberFormat: "'ZAR '#,###.##00",
        });

        // Set themes
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
        root.setThemes([
            am5themes_Animated.new(root),
            am5themes_Responsive.new(root),
            Amdg.new(root)
        ]);
        // Create chart
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
        var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
            panX: true,
            panY: true,
            wheelX: "panX",
            wheelY: "zoomX",
            pinchZoomX:true
            }));
        // Add cursor
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
        var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
        behavior: "none"
        }));
        cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);



        // Define data
        var data = {{ line_chart_data| safe }}
        
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i]["chart_dated_dt"] = new Date(data[i]["chart_dated_dt"]).getTime();
        }

        // Create axes
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
        // Create Y-axis
        let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
        am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
            maxDeviation: 0.1,
            renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
        })
        );


        var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
            am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
                maxDeviation: 0.1,
                groupData: true,
                groupIntervals: [
                    { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 }
                    ],
                baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
                renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
                }),
                tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
            })
            );

        xAxis.get("dateFormats")["day"] = "MM/dd";
        xAxis.get("periodChangeDateFormats")["day"] = "MMMM";
        
        xAxis.data.setAll(data);
        // Add series
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/line-series/
        function createSeries(name, field) {
        var series = chart.series.push( 
            am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, { 
            name: name,
            xAxis: xAxis, 
            yAxis: yAxis,
            valueYField: field, 
            valueXField: "chart_dated_dt",
            stacked: false,
            tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
                pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
                labelText: "{valueY}",
                })

            })
        );
        
        series.strokes.template.setAll({
            strokeWidth: 2,
            //strokeDasharray: [2,1]
        });
        series.fills.template.setAll({
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            visible: false
        });
        series.data.setAll(data);

        }
        
        chart.topAxesContainer.children.push(am5.Label.new(root, {
            text: "Performance",
            fontSize: 30,
            fontColor: '#e40505',
            fontWeight: "500",
            textAlign: "center",
            x: am5.percent(50),
            centerX: am5.percent(50),
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingBottom: 20,
        }));

        // Add cursor
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
        var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
            xAxis: xAxis
            }));
        cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);


        createSeries("Average Contributions", "average_contrib");
        createSeries("Average Contributions + Interest", "average_totals");
        createSeries("Median Contributions", "median_contrib");
        createSeries("Median Contributions + Interest", "median_totals");
        createSeries("Your Contributions", "user_contrib");
        createSeries("Your Contributions + Interest", "user_totals");

        var legend = chart.bottomAxesContainer.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
            centerX: am5.percent(50),
            x: am5.percent(50),
            useDefaultMarker: true,
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingBottom: 20,
            layout: am5.GridLayout.new(root, {
                maxColumns: 3,
                fixedWidthGrid: true
            })
        }));
        legend.data.setAll(chart.series.values);

        // Add scrollbar
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/scrollbars/

        var scrollbarX = am5xy.XYChartScrollbar.new(root, {
            orientation: "horizontal",
            height: 50
            });
        
        let sbxAxis = scrollbarX.chart.xAxes.push(
            am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
                groupData: true,
                groupIntervals: [
                    { timeUnit: "month", count: 1 }
                    ],
                baseInterval: { timeUnit: "day", count: 1 },
                renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
                    opposite: false,
                    strokeOpacity: 0
                })
            })
            );

        let sbyAxis = scrollbarX.chart.yAxes.push(
            am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
                renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
            })
        );

        let sbseries = scrollbarX.chart.series.push(
            am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
                xAxis: sbxAxis,
                yAxis: sbyAxis,
                valueYField: "user_totals", 
                valueXField: "chart_dated_dt",
            })
            );
        sbseries.strokes.template.setAll({
            strokeWidth: 2,
            //strokeDasharray: [2,1]
        });
        sbseries.data.setAll(data);
        chart.set("scrollbarX", scrollbarX);


        // Make stuff animate on load
        // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
        
        sbseries.appear(1000, 100);
        console.log(chart.series)
        console
        root._logo.dispose();
        chart.appear(1000, 100);
        }); // end am5.ready()
</script>
```